# How to sort pandas dataframe by month name

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe

I have the following data frame:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5CMd.png
(44 rows)

I tried sorting it by using CategoricalIndex() but found out it can only be done if there are no repeat in month values. Any one know how to sort it chronologically.

Comment: add column with month number, sort by that column, drop it later

Comment: You can sort using both month and year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always try to post your code.
In this way we could figure out why your categorical sorting did not work out. But I suspect you forgot the `ordered=True` parameter.

Categorical ordering allows sorting according to a custom order, and works perfectly for this case. It also handles well duplicated month values. Here is my code:

```
df["month"] = pd.Categorical(df["month"],
                             categories=["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",
                                         "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
                             ordered=True)
```

And after that we can call the function `sort_values()`:

```
df = df.sort_values(["year", "month"], ignore_index=True)
```

Cheers and keep it up!

Comment: Thank you! I did find a solution before your comment but this is much more elegant than the method I used

Comment: Glad it helped!
Not necessarily for this post, but you can mark (or unmark) one of the answers as the accepted answer.
This “docks” the accepted answer under the question, and helps others finding best answers.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps

```
# Add new column in format YYYYMM
df['year_month'] = df['year'] + (pd.to_datetime(df.month , format='%B').dt.month.astype(str).str.zfill(2))
# sort values
df.sort_values(by=['year_month'], inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
df['date']=(df['month']+' '+df['year'])
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df=df.sort_values('date')
```